# XCTest is not giving me accurate results each time (Sometimes it fails, sometimes it passes)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xctest, uitest

I am using XCode 8.2.1 (Swift) with XCode UI tests to test my app in terms of UI, so my problem with this tool is it doesn't give me accurate results some tests are passed and at the next time they fail.

My question might be generic but is this problem related to me or is it common one? i believe this happened after migrating to XCode 7+

Do you guys recommend using anther tool for UI tests other than this one? as am looking for faster, accurate and ability to integrate with a CI server.

Comment: You should specify your problem. It's too large.

Comment: Show one of your tests that behaves this way.

Comment: I have experienced this kind of inconsistency. In some cases, it was caused by the way the test was set up, in other cases it seemed to be unreliability of the test framework.

Comment: I just need to know if this a common problem or just my case. i can edit my post and share one of the tests but as i said its a regular one.

Comment: Perhaps you are experiencing a race condition. XCTest can be quite fast so try using expectationForPredicate and waitForExpectationsWithTimeout - these might stabilise your tests. Can't give any more advice without specifics of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
private func waitForElementToAppear(element: XCUIElement,
                                    file: String = #file, line: UInt = #line) {
    let existsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "exists == true")
    expectation(for: existsPredicate,
                evaluatedWith: element, handler: nil)

    waitForExpectations(timeout: 30) { (error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            let message = "Failed to find \(element) after 30 seconds."
            self.recordFailure(withDescription: message,
                               inFile: file, atLine: line, expected: true)
        }
    }
}
```

invoke this method and avoid test fails because sometimes our UI takes more time to getting result from Server.